# Meteor build is killed when deploying on cloud foundry

Tags: meteor, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

We are deploying a Meteor application on Swisscom's Cloud Foundry. The `meteor build` command, part of the buildpack we are using, is being killed. This does not happen always, but the deplyoment process is not reliable because of this.

The error message is:

`/tmp/buildpacks/ccde798f181156726dc68059bc038932/bin/compile: line 64:    99 Killed                  meteor build --directory deploy --server http://localhost:3000 --architecture os.linux.x86_64`

We are using a buildpack forked from cloudfoundry-community. It can be found here:
https://github.com/vl4d1m1r4/cf-meteor-buildpack. The command being killed can be found on line 70 inside bin/compile.

Any insight on why this is happening would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to a lack of sufficient resource assigned to the app, if it's running out of memory during compilation, CF will destroy the container and the meteor process within. Run `cf events <appname>` to see if the container is being purposefully destroyed and if it is due to insufficient memory, assign more!

Comment: Memory was indeed the problem. We had considered this earlier, but underestimated the amount of memory needed. Currently the build process uses more memory than the application itself. We will probably drop the buildpack in favor of a build process that runs locally and only uploads the  application.